# Как убрать первое совпадение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

После такого кода в `$matchs` будет массив с двумя значениями

```
preg_match('/^test([0-9])$/i', 'test1', $matchs);
```

Первое это полная строка `test1`, и второе число `1`

Как можно оставить только число? Мне нужен массив без `test1`

Comment: @Alex отчего же? Представленное регулярное выражение выберез как-раз test1, так-что первым элементом массива будет "test1", а вторым "1" (вхождение первой подмаски, т.е. "([0-9])")

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/^test([0-9])$/i', 'test1', $matchs);
$foo = $matchs[1];
```

Ну или если нужен именно массив то:

```
$foo = Array( $matchs[1] );
```

Стоит ещё добавить проверку `$matchs`, например так:

```
preg_match('/^test([0-9])$/i', 'test1', $matchs);
if ( sizeof($matchs) > 1 ) {
    $foo = $matchs[1];
}
```

Comment: лучше добавить проверку на `preg_match` иначе warning в случае отсутствия элемента с индексом 1.

Comment: Да, про проверки забывать не стоит, что-бы не иметь потом сконфуженный вид (:

Comment: Это такой вид который бывает у программиста когда, например, продакшен упал на пару часов из-за того что он не подумал добавить проверку на тот случай что входящие данные не будут соответствовать его ожиданиям

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса не относится к регулярным выражениям.
Вам нужно производить операции с результирующим массивом, чтобы убрать лишние совпадения.
Изучите руководство, что возвращает функция `preg_match`:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

**Правильный путь** решения задачи: преобразовать массив, например так:

```
$result = $matchs[1];
```

**Неправильный путь** - искать такие регулярные выражения, которые "*не будут захватывать лишнего*", например такое:

```
preg_match( '/(?<=^test)[0-9]$/i', 'test1', $matchs );
```

Comment: Дело в том, что может быть неопределенное кол-во чисел: preg_match('/^test([0-9])-([0-9])$/i', 'test1', $matchs);

Comment: В таком случае Вы неправильно сформулировали вопрос. Я не экстрасенс.